# How to return the best first level in this F# minimax?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, f#, minimax

This question is more a semantic-algorithmic-data-structure question than a F# syntactically question.
I have a Minimax algorithm. The minimax algorithm should return the best next move, from a start position. To do this, it calculus all next moves, then the next-next-moves until a determined depth or until there is no more moves. It builds a tree like this:

```
     P  
   /  \  
 a      b  
/ \  
c d
```

I have the fallowing data struct to handle the tree:

```
type TreeOfPosition =
    | LeafP   of Position * int
    | BranchP of Position * TreeOfPosition list
```

In the exemple tree above, `P` and `a` are Branchs and `b`, `c` and `d` are Leafs. The code below is my minimax algorithm:

```
let evaluateTree ( tree : TreeOfPosition, player : int) =
    let rec loop minOrmax node =
        match node with
        | LeafP(position, 0) -> 
            LeafP(position, evaluateLeaf(position))
        | BranchP(position, children)  -> 
            minimax.[minOrmax](List.map (loop (1 - minOrmax)) children)
    loop player tree
```

This code are returning me a Leaf, for example, `c`. When I changed the recursion call to

```
| BranchP(position, children)  -> 
    LeafP(position, 
          getStaticEvalFromNode(minimax.[minOrmax](
                       List.map (loop (1 - minOrmax)) children)))
```

And this modification makes the static value of a good leaf go up.
I need to return the best second level node. 
Hope somebody can help!
Pedro Dusso

**EDIT 1**

Thanks for all answers guys, they help me a lot. Sorry about didn't specified the things very much. Let's go in parts:

1) I’m matching my LeafP like `LeafP(position, 0)` because when I create my tree I set the leafs with a default value of 0 as its static value. As I’m going up my static values, eliminating the leaf and making the (before Branches) leafs with (min or max) static values I thought that this way I would prevent to evaluate a ex-Branch leaf (because it would not have the 0 value).

2) My biggest problem was to get the second level (the next move which has to be played) best position back. I solved it this way:

```
let evaluateTreeHOF ( tree, player : int) =
    let rec loop minOrmax node =
        match node with
        | LeafP(position, 0) -> LeafP(position, evaluateLeaf(position))
        | BranchP(position, children) -> LeafP(position,(children 
                                                         |> List.map (loop (1 - minOrmax)) 
                                                         |> minimax.[minOrmax] 
                                                         |> getStaticEvalFromNode))
    match tree with
    | BranchP(position, children) -> children |> List.map (loop (1 - player)) |> minimax.[player]
```

Instead of passing the entire tree, I’m passing just the children’s of the start node, and filtering the resulted list (a list of ex-Branches with the static values which went up for be the best for its current level) again. This way I’m getting the node I wanted.

I thought the kvb answers very interesting, but a little complicated to me. The other ones I understudied, but they just give me back the static value – and I could not make them to work for me :(

Thanks a lot for all the answers, all of them inspired me a lot.

Here is my full code: (http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~pmdusso/works/Functional_Implementation_Minimax_FSharp.htm)

Pedro Dusso

Comment: Could you elaborate your question some more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand some aspects of your sample (e.g. why do you match only against leaves with 0s in them?), so I'll make a few changes below.  First of all, let's generalize the tree type a bit, so that it can store any types of data in the leaves and branches:

```
type Tree<'a,'b> = 
| Leaf of 'a 
| Branch of 'b * Tree<'a,'b> list
```

Let's also use a dedicated player type, rather than using 0 or 1:

```
type Player = Black | White
```

Finally, let's generalize the evaluation of the best move a bit, so that the leaf evaluation function is passed in as an argument:

```
let bestMove evalPos player tree =
  // these replace your minimax function array
  let agg1,agg2,aggBy = 
    match player with
    | Black -> List.min, List.max, List.maxBy
    | White -> List.max, List.min, List.minBy

  // given a tree, this evaluates the score for that tree
  let rec score agg1 agg2 = function
  | Leaf(p) -> evalPos p
  | Branch(_,l) -> agg1 (List.map (score agg2 agg1) l)

  // now we use just need to pick the branch with the highest score
  // (or lowest, depending on the player)
  match tree with
  | Leaf(_) -> failwith "Cannot make any moves from a Leaf!"
  | Branch(_,l) -> aggBy (score agg1 agg2) l
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use mutually recursive functions:

```
let maxTree t = 
  match t with
  | child -> xxx
  | subtrees s ->
      s |> Seq.map minTree |> Seq.max

and minTree t = 
  match t with
  | child -> xxx
  | subtrees s ->
      s |> Seq.map maxTree |> Seq.min
```

Comment: I did not understand what are the child and the subtrees in your code. Are the leafs and the branchs? I ask this because a subtree is a child from a uper node... I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was described in the F#.NET Journal article *[Games programming: tic-tac-toe](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/01/games-programming-tic-tac-toe.html)* (31st December 2009) and uses the following pattern:

```
type t = Leaf | Branch of t seq

let aux k = function
  | Leaf -> []
  | Branch s -> k s

let rec maxTree t = aux (Seq.map minTree >> Seq.max) t
and minTree t = aux (Seq.map maxTree >> Seq.min) t
```

See also the [playable demo](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/02/tic-tac-toe-demo.html).

Comment: We can only read this paper subscribing to The F#.NET Journal? :(

Comment: Jon, I tested your solution. It works, but this way it returns me the static value of the leaf node, and I'm searching the entire nodo to play it. Maybe with some modifications. All answers here inspired me to write my own solution, which I will add to my question editing it.